# Regex con rango de 1 a 20 que acepte 2 decimales

Tags: c#, regex, xaml, devexpress

hola, estoy usando una mascara de RegEx en un control TextEdit de DevExpress y quiero que tenga un rango de 1 a 20 y que acepte dos decimales, la mascara que tengo actualmente acepta de 1 a 99 con dos decimales

```
\d{0,2}(\.\d{1,2})?
```

Agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: Algo como `^([1-9]|1\d|20)(\.\d{1,2})?$`?

Comment: @Pikoh, me funcionó muy bien, muchas gracias! :)

Comment: Hay un problema con el regex que te puse. Aceptaría hasta `20.99` ...A ver si algun experto te lo soluciona :)

Comment: esta me funciona ^(20\.00)|([1-9]|1\d)(\.\d{1,2})?$

Comment: @gbianchi gracias! funciona ;)

Comment: si pero solo si escribis 20.00.. si escribis solo 20 no anda.. hay que refinarla mas todavia...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usa el siguiente Regex

```
^((20\.00)|20|((1\d|[1-9])(\.\d{1,2})?))$
```

A diferencia los comentarios este regex no hace match con `0` u otros números entre `20` y `21` y a diferencia del comentario de @gbianchi sí hace match con `20`(al igual que con `20.0` y `20.00`)